# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'add') | React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im new to coding and Im trying to make a "page not found" page  but im getting the following error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'add')
```

How can I solve this problem?

Here is the code:

```
  setTimeout(function () {
    const notFoundElement = document.getElementsByClassName(
      "not-found-animation"
    );
    notFoundElement.classNameList.add("hinge-falling");

    console.log("setTimeout Loaded...");
  }, 2200);
```

```
<h1 className="not-found-animation">404</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the original DOM in React (bad practice).

### solutions

- Using useState Hook

```js
const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false);
setTimeout(function () {
  setToggle(!toggle);

  console.log("setTimeout Loaded...");
}, 2200);
<h1 className={`${toggle && "not-found-animation"}`}>404</h1>;
```

- Using useRef Hook

```js
const ref = useRef(null);
setTimeout(function () {
  const h1 = ref.current; // corresponding DOM node
  h1.className = "not-found-animation";
  console.log("setTimeout Loaded...");
}, 2200);

<h1 ref={ref}>404</h1>;
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to access the first element in the collection using [0],
Try:

```
 setTimeout(function () {
      const notFoundElement = document.getElementsByClassName(
        "not-found-animation"
      );
      notFoundElement[0].classList.add("hinge-falling");
    
      console.log("setTimeout Loaded...");
    }, 2200);
```

Answer (score -1):

try this notFoundElement.setAttribute('class','hinge-falling')

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).